# Determining Xi does not have a mean based on a density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I’d like a nod in the right direction as the question of *if* the mean exists makes me think of two different cases.

The problem states:

Let $X_1, X_2…, X_n$ be iid  random variables with density function:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $|x|$ is $\le$ 2}\\[2ex]
\frac{c}{x^2log|x|}, & \text{if $|x|$ is $\gt$ 2}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $X_i$ has no mean.

My initial thoughts were something about discontinuity but I don't think that is a precursor for the existence of a mean (How else could we have discrete random variables for instance). I assume this is either base 2 or e (as it isn't specified) but then would I just need show E($X_i$)=$\infty$? I am a bit unsure what is being asked so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ has no mean  if $E|X| = \infty$. But in your case
$$
E|X|=\int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} |x| f(x)\, dx = 2\int_2^\infty \frac{c}{x\log x}
$$
which you can show diverges.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that’s all they wanted but thank you for supplying the explicit definition of the existence! For clarity, you combined the expressions for the negative and positive portions of the integral and simplified the x terms hence we no longer have $x^2$ in the denominator correct?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did